# How to pass system commands in wpf

Tags: wpf, command, system, shutdown

I want to make a simple wpf application that allows the user to set a timer for when they want their computer to shutdown. I have made such a program previously as a c++ console application, by simply passing a command "system(shutdown -s -f 6000)" - (shutdown in 6000 seconds. How would I go about doing this in a wpf application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke all shell commands using the following construct, e.g. to run the shutdown command:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "shutdown -s -t 60000");
```

This would display the command prompt window, if that is not desired, you can a ProcessStartInfo to the process:

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C shutdown -s -t 60000";

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks alot! At first it didn't work, because the shell command that you used in your example is invalid, but all I had to do was delete the -f flag and replace it with -t. Works like a charm. Thanks again.

Comment: sorry, must have been a typo, I'll fix the solution.